# Assembly 8086 - copy one buffer to another

Tags: assembly, x86-16

im working on a assembly program that reads the whole text file into a buffer then displays it in the console. It displays 24 lines (each line has a max lenght of 80, because im using a 80 wide * 25 height dossbox ) at once then waits for user input so the user can scroll through the text.

I wanted to add the number of line to the beginning of each line, so figured i could make a second buffer and copy chars 1by1 from the first one and when i find a newline i would call a procedure which would add the line number to the buffer, then continue till i proceed thru the whole buffer. But my way of copying from one buffer to the other is bad.

So i wanna copy 
BUFFA to BUFFB:

```
mov di,OFFSET BUFFB ;so i set di to the beggining of bufferB




mov si,Pos         ;Pos is my position in the first buffer
lea bx,BUFFA[si]   ;move the content of buffA to bx , i think the problem is here
mov [di],bx        ;move to the addres of di the content of bx
inc di
inc Pos
```

the problem is when i print out the content of the second buffer i find out that i copy the value of si(same as Pos) to my buffer and not the content of the bufferA[si]. How can i fix this code?

Edit 1:

So the solution is using mov and al register:

```
mov si,Pos
mov al,[BUFF + si]
mov [di],al
inc di
```

Comment: `lea` (load extended address) loads the _address_ of the argument, not the content. You actually want a `mov` here.

Comment: ty for your fast answer, but mov bx, offset BUFFB[si] is not legal operation

Comment: Remove the `offset` part.

Comment: Ty. Also i have to use al register and remove the offset part.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError just for the record, it's load **effective** address, not extended.

Comment: @Jester: Doh! brainfart! - thx.

Answer (score 10):

you can use

```
lodsb
```

instead of

```
mov al,[si]
inc si
```

and

```
stosb
```

instead of

```
mov [di],al
inc di
```

in best cases, you can combine both to

```
movsb    ; move byte at [si] to [di], and increase both indices
```

if you know how many bytes to copy, you can even move memory blocks using "rep", which repeats the instruction afterwards CX times:

```
cld                    ; make sure that movsb copies forward
mov si, source_buffer
mov di, dest_buffer
mov cx, #amount of bytes to copy
rep movsb
```

or fill memory blocks

```
cld                  ; make sure that stosb moves forward
mov si, buffer       ; start here
mov al, 0xFF         ; fill with 0xFF
mov cx, #20          ; 20 times
rep stosb
```

if you're using words instead of bytes, use lodsw, stosw  and movsw

All these instructions can either go 
- forward (INC si/di) when the direction flag is cleared (via CLD)  or 
 - backwards (DEC si/di). when the direction flag is set (via STD)

Comment: You might improve your answer by including the `CLD` instruction. It's all-important with string primitives and all too often neglected.

Comment: Thanks. I also edited your answer to correct a few mistakes (probably due to haste?) Upvoted!