# Assembly 8086 : How to Make thanks with a loop and video memory

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I need a program that show at the center the write "Thanks" with heart symbols in left and right side of the text, but the hearts with red color and the text with green color.
I have now this code:

```
mov ax, 0B800h
mov es, ax
mov di,spiazz
mov byte ptr es:[di+0], ' '
mov byte ptr es:[di+2], ' '
mov byte ptr es:[di+4], ' '
mov byte ptr es:[di+1], 20h
mov byte ptr es:[di+3], 70h
mov byte ptr es:[di+5], 40h
```

With a similar code like this, I need to show an "heart(symbol)Thanks heart(symbol)";
but with the hearts red and the text green.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can mov-immediate a whole word, instead of the bytes separately.  like `mov word ptr es:[di+2], (20h<<8) + ' '`.  That's much more efficient than 2 separate byte-store instructions.

Comment: thanks Peter Cordes

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  You already know how to store into video memory.  And how do you want to make a loop?  Do you want to copy from somewhere else?  If your data is immediate values, you can't loop because you need to store a different value in each instruction.

Comment: Can you make an example, please?

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks too much

Comment: [Assembly 8086 - copy one buffer to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36142905) shows a copy using `rep movsb`.  You'd probably want `rep movsw` to copy words from a preset buffer.  Or you'd want to loop and load from a byte string and add colour attributes, like `lodsb` / `stosw` with AH = constant attributes.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Below is one of these:

```
    mov  ax, 0B800h                ;Points to the 80x25 text screen
    mov  es, ax
    mov  di, (13-1)*160+(37-1)*2   ;Print At(37,13);    //Column 37, Row 13
    mov  si, msg
    cld                            ;This makes SI and DI move  f o r w a r d  as is needed
    mov  ax, 0403h                 ;AL=3 (heart character) AH=04h (RedOnBlack)
    push ax                        ;(1) Preserve on the stack
LL:
    stosw
    mov  ah, 02h                   ;GreenOnBlack
    lodsb
    cmp  al, 0                     ;Message was zero-terminated
    jne  LL                        ;Terminator not yet reached
    pop  ax                        ;(1) Restore from the stack
    stosw                          ;This outputs the second heart character

    ...

msg db 'Thanks', 0
```

Do pay special attention to the comments! Don't just copy-paste it.